# Website google oauth needed

Tags: python, google-oauth

Probably this was already answered somewhere, but my google-fu can't get proper keywords for this.
Ok so, I need to get a file from my site which is like *foo.bar/foobar/file.ext* . That file is always accessible but if you aren't google-authenticated on the site you get a blank file. 
How can I get proper authentication with python? 
Sorry if this isn't very clear but it's my first time here... Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score -1):

First install the [Python SDK here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation).

Then I would start reading about [OAuth here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth).

They have different examples depending on your use case. (e.g. If you are authenticating a user from their browser, versus from server to server)

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon on SO, partly because when links break, the answers become worthless. Consider how useful your answer would be if the hyperlinks were removed (more on that on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). E.g. instead of "First install the Python SDK here." I would say "First install the Google APIs Client Library for Python", that way later users can still google text from your answer even if link rot sets in.